# Getting started with denoising elements of a 200x200 numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I have a 200x200 numpy array that has a shape in it which I can see when I graph it using matplotlib's `imshow()` function. However, there is also a lot of noise added in that picture. I am trying to use openCV to emphasize the shape and denoise the image. But it keeps throwing error messages that I don't understand. What should I do to get started on the denoising problem. The shape is visible to me as I see it but extra noise was added using the `np.random.randint()` function on top of the image. I want to reduce that noise

Comment: How about showing the image? Or better, save the array as an image to disk and post the image so others can test ways to process it.

Comment: I am voting to close this question on the basis that there is little chance of being able to answer unless the image is provided. As it is there is no indication of whether the image is greyscale or colour or how the noise appears or is distributed or how its intensity relates to the signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using Scikit Image. They have very accessible documentation page for new comers and the error messages are a lot easier to understand. As for my problem I had to use [Scikit Image's restoration library](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html) which has a lot of denoising functions much like openCV however the examples and the easy to understand error messages really helped. Playing around with [Bilateral filters](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_denoise.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-filters-plot-denoise-py) and [Non-local Means Denoising](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_nonlocal_means.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-filters-plot-nonlocal-means-py) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials about image denoising techniques available in opencv.

#### Blurring out the noise

The most basic is applying a [blur](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) to average out the random noise. This will have the negative effect that the edges in the image will not be as sharp as originally. Depending on your application, this might be fine. Depending on the amount of noise, you can chance the size of the filter `k`. A larger value will produce a blurrier image with less noise.

```py
k = 5
filtered_image = cv.blur(img,(k,k))
```

### Advanced denoising

Alternatively, you can use more advanced techniques such as [Non-local Means Denoising](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html). This applies averaging across similar patches in the image. This technique has a few more parameters to tune to your specific application which you can read about [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga03aa4189fc3e31dafd638d90de335617). (There are different versions of this function for greyscale and colour images, as well as for image sequences).

```py
luminosity_filter_strength = 10
colour_filter_strength = 10
template_window_size = 7
search_window_size = 21
filtered_image = cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,
        luminosity_filter_strength,
        colour_filter_strength,
        template_window_size,
        search_window_size)
```

Comment: I was having a hard time working with OpenCV, since I am new to it. Scikit image documentation and examples did the job for me.